# Better alternatives to linear regression and $AR(1)$ for modeling cointegrated time series

Tags: time-series, cointegration

In a cointegration framework, I would like to improve the two-step Engle-Granger cointegration procedure.

My idea is to:

1. replace the linear regression with some non-linear model;
2. replace the $AR(1)$ residuals with some more advanced forecasting model.

An example could be:

1. replace linear regression with a LOESS or a decision tree;
2. replace the $AR(1)$ residuals with [Prophet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/vignettes/quick_start.html) or [TBATS](https://pkg.robjhyndman.com/forecast/reference/tbats.html) model.

The main goal is to take into account non-linearities in the cointegration relation as well as to manage residuals that can exhibit behavior with structural breaks instead of just converging to the long term mean. There so many choices for both (1) and (2) that I'm struggling to find a good solution. What are the more consistent candidates to replace linear regression and $AR(1)$ models in a bivariate cointegration framework to get a better model?